# When is it possible to transform limits using substitution?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, limits, multivariable-calculus

In calculus, if I have to calculate $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$, we can usually do substitutions of the from $x=\phi(y)$ and then our limit would be $\lim_{y \to \phi(x_0)}f(\phi(y))$. However, we cannot just choose some arbitrary $\phi$. 
As a counterexample, take $\lim_{x \to 2}x$. You cannot take $x=\phi(y)=0$, so my intuition says that $\phi$ needs to be bijective in a small enough neighbourhood of $x_0$. Also, I would assume that $\phi$ needs to be continuous at $x_0$. The substitution $\phi(x)=\text{floor}(x)$ would also fail, firstly because of non-injectivity, but also because of non-continuity.

Do we need any more conditions on $\phi$?

> For context, the reason why I am asking this is because in my university coursed, our profesor said that if we want to calculate $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}f(x, y)$, we can just change to polar coordinates and calculate and it would be easier. I am currently studying engineering, so I would be looking for some theoretical, pure maths proof on the restrictions of the substitution $(x, y)=\phi(u, v)$.

To rephrase my question.

Given two topological spaces $(T, \tau_T)$, $(S, \tau_S)$ and $(U, \tau_U)$, $D \subseteq T$, a function $f\colon D \to S$ and $x_0$ an accumulation point of $D$. Now let $V$ be a neighbourhood of $x_0$ and $\phi\colon U \to D \cap V$. What would be the minimum conditions that $\phi$ needs to obey such that $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=\lim_{y \to \phi(x_0)}f(\phi(y))$?

Is the bijectivity and continuity of $\phi$ equivalent to the equality of limits in the general case? My intuition says yes, however from working a lot in abstract algebra these types of substitutions required $\phi$ to be an isomorphism, in our case shouldn't $\phi$ be a homeomorphism? I can't think of a counterexample where if $\phi$ is continuous and bijective would fail if $\phi^-1$ is not continuous?

And one more thing, the polar coordinates substitution "fails", if we work on the direct product of the extended real number line, at points that have infinity on one component, since I don't think polar coordinates are defined just like how the angle isn't defined for the origin.

Comment: Roughly, if you need to establish that the limit exists, then both $\varphi$ and its inverse need to be continuous. If you're assuming (or already know) that the limit exists, and are just trying to find the value, then the inverse doesn't matter. Although heck, in that case you just need a path, or even just a sequence, that converges to your point.

Comment: The polar coordinate substitution (given $z$ pick $(r, \theta)$ such that $z = re^{i\theta}$) is a bit problematic. It isn't a bijection, but it becomes one if you choose a branch cut so that you only have one pair $(r, \theta)$ for each $z$. Having done that the resulting $\phi$ is not continuous (its inverse is). However it is continuous at $0$, and that's all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first remark that the expression $\lim_{y \to \phi(x_0)}f(\phi(y))$ does not make sense. You have to replace it by
$$\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y))$$
where $\phi(y_0) = x_0$. Thus the minimal requirement is that $\phi^{-1}(x_0) \ne \emptyset$.

Then your question is

> Given two topological spaces $(T, \tau_T)$, $(S, \tau_S)$ and a subset $D \subseteq T$, a function $f\colon D \to S$ and an accumulation point $x_0$ of $D$. Now let $V$ be a neighbourhood of $x_0$ and $\phi\colon U \to D \cap V$ a function defined on a topological space $(U,\tau_U)$, and let $y_0 \in U$ such that $\phi(y_0) = x_0$. What are the minimum conditions that $\phi$ needs to obey such that $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y))$?

Note that this is only possible when $x_0 = \phi(y_0) \in D$.

Independent of an intended substitution, when we consider a function $f : D \to S$ such that $x_0 \notin D$, we can define $D_0 = D \cup \{x_0\}$ and extend $f$ to $f_0 : D_0 \to S$ by choosing an element $s_0 \in S$ and defining $f(x_0) = s_0$. Then
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0} f_0(x) .$$
For the limit on the RHS it irrelevant which $s_0$ we chose. We have  $\lim_{x \to x_0} f_0(x) = s_0$ iff $f_0$ is continuous at $x_0$, but that has nothing to do with the question.

Thus we may assume that $x_0 \in D$. Doing so, the bigger space $T \supset D$ does not play any role: The elements of $T \setminus D$ have no influence on the limit. Thus we get the question

> Given two topological spaces $(T, \tau_T)$, $(S, \tau_S)$ and a function $f \colon T \to S$ and an accumulation point $x_0$ of $T$. Now let $V$ be a neighbourhood of $x_0$ and $\phi\colon U \to V$ a function defined on a topological space $(U,\tau_U)$, and let $y_0 \in U$ such that $\phi(y_0) = x_0$. What are the minimum conditions that $\phi$ needs to obey such that $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y))$?

Usually one works with a *homeomorphism* $\phi : U \to V$ and calls it a *local substitution around $x_0$* ("coordinate change"). Then

- $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ exists iff $\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y))$ exists.
- In that case the limits agree.

We are looking for more general $\phi$.

Let us first explore under what conditions on $\phi$ the existence of $\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y))$ implies that
$$\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = \lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) .\tag{1}$$

Here is the minimal condition (for a *general* $f$, in special cases like $f = $ const no conditions are needed):

1. For each open neighborhood $U'$ of $y_0$ the image $\phi(U')$ contains an open neighborhood of $x_0$.

Under this condition we can prove $(1)$ for **any** $f$:

Let $\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) = L$. We claim that also $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L$. Let $W$ be an open neighborhood of $L$. There exists an open neighborhood $U'$ of $y_0$ such that $f(\phi(y)) \in W$ for $y \in U' \setminus \{y_0\}$. But $\phi(U')$ contains an open neigbborhood $V$ of $x_0$, and we get $f(x) \in W$ for all $x \in V \setminus \{x_0\}$ [Pick $y \in U'$ with $\phi(y) = x$ which requires $y  \ne y_0$; then $f(x) = f(\phi(y)) \in W$.]

What happens if 1. is violated?

Then some $\phi(U')$ does not contain an open neighborhood of $x_0$. We can at best expect that
$$\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) = \lim_{y \to y_0,y \in U'}f(\phi(y)) = \lim_{x \to x_0 x \in \phi(U')} f(x)$$
But we can also approach $x_0$ by points in $T \setminus \phi(U')$ - and do not know anything about the behavior of $f$ on $T \setminus \phi(U')$. It may very well happen that $\lim_{x \to x_0 x \in T \setminus \phi(U')} f(x)$ does not exist or is different from $\lim_{x \to x_0 x \in \phi(U')} f(x)$.

Condition 1. means that *the function $\phi$ is open at $y_0$* which is a sort of "dual" variant of $\phi$ being continuous at $y_0$.

Let us finally explore under what conditions on $\phi$ the existence of $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ implies that
$$\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) =  \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) .\tag{2}$$

A minimal condition is that

2. $\phi$ is continuous at $y_0$.

If it is not, then the limit $\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y))$, if it exists, is in general not related to $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$. Assume for example that $\lim_{y \to y_0}\phi(y)$ exists with value $\xi \ne x_0$. Then there is no reason why $(2)$ should be true.

If $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = f(x_0)$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0 = \phi(y_0)$ so that $f \circ \phi$ is continuous at $y_0$ which implies $$\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) = f(\phi(y_0)) = f(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) .$$

If  $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) \ne f(x_0)$, this argument breaks down. In this case we require

3. There exists an open neighborhood $U_0$ of $y_0$ such that $x_0 \notin \phi(U_0 \setminus \{y_0\})$.

Under conditions 2. and 3. we can prove $(2)$ for **any** $f$:

Let $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L$. We claim that also $\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) = L$. Let $W$ be an open neighborhood of $L$. There exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x) \in W$ for $x \in V \setminus \{x_0\}$. Since $\phi$ is continuous at $y_0$, there exists an open neighborhood $U'$ of $y_0$ such that $\phi(y) \in V$ for $y \in U'$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $U' \subset U_0$. Then $f(\phi(y)) \in W$ for all $y \in U' \setminus \{y_0\}$.

What happens if 2. is violated?

Then for each neighborhood $U'$ of $y_0$ we have $x_0 \in \phi(U' \setminus \{y_0\})$. Then, if $\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y))$ exists and $\{f(x_0)\}$ is closed in $S$, we get $\lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) = f(x_0) \ne L$. In fact, assume that $L' = \lim_{y \to y_0}f(\phi(y)) \ne f(x_0)$. Then $W = S \setminus \{f(x_0)\}$ is an open neigborhood of $L'$ and there exists an open neighborhood $U'$ of $y_0$ such that $f(\phi(y)) \in W$ for $y \in U' \setminus \{y_0\}$. But $x_0 \in \phi(U' \setminus \{y_0\})$, thus there exists $y_1  \in U' \setminus \{y_0\}$ with $\phi(y_1) = x_0$. Hence $f(\phi(y_1)) = f(x_0) \notin W$, a contradiction.

Comment: $W\subset V$ seems wrong; $W$ lives in $S$ whereas $V$ lives in $T$. Also, it seems that both instances of $U_0$ are meant to say $U'$?

Comment: @joriki Thank you pointing out the typo concerning $U_0$. The assumption on $W$ does not make any sense and is irrelevaat anyway. I deleted it.